# Automation of Loopback Adapter install on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, loopback

I have a piece of Software that requires a Loopback Adapter on Windows.

Is there some sort of scripting or a batch file that could automate installing and setting up a Loopback Adapter with a certain IP/Subnet Mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to install the Microsoft Loopback Adapter in Microsoft Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842561).

It describes how to use the devcon utility to install it as follows :

```
devcon.exe install %windir%\inf\netloop.inf *msloop
```

devcon may already be installed on your computer, and if not, better make sure you get the right version, or at least test the [download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe) that is included in the article.

Comment: How come you can only create 5 network adapters? http://superuser.com/questions/737767/use-devcon-to-create-multiple-loopback-adapters